# Can I hand over UIImage to Native Photos app for photo editing?

Tags: ios, ios8

I have picked `UIImage` from this

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

But I am still not able to figure out how can I hand over `UIImage` object to Photos app for editing?

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: This sounds like you want to pass it to another app outside your designated container which can't be done. You can save your photo to the photo library and then go to the photo app and open it up there.

Comment: Yeah thanks man I got it now, I was trying to do something which isn't possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a new UIImageView on other view controller and pass this image using prepareForSegue method.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"editphoto"])
 {
    YourNextViewController*editImageView=segue.destinationViewController;
    UIImage*clickedImage=capturedPicImageView.image;
    editImageView.passedImage=clickedImage;
   // NSLog(@"%@",editView.editPhotoImgView.image);
 }
}

(And in YourNextViewController create UIImage*clickedImage and give property to it. and        dont forget to allocate in viewDidLoad. Hope this helps.
```